# How to fetch page number of bookmark in html

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I have multiple bookmarks in html Document. I am trying to create a link to these bookmarks. Link works absolutely fine.I need to mention the page numbers of the bookmark as well.

Below is the code.

```
<a href="#bookmark1">PAGE_NUMBER</a>
```

How do I fetch value for `PAGE_NUMBER` of the bookmark location?

Comment: can you post Your code ..

Comment: Yash ?????????????????

Comment: Hi RishiKesh,Sorry for the delay. Actually there are few things. Mine is an word document which is created using html input + open office. I can share the document. Can I get your mail id?

Comment: okzz... kumarrishikesh12@gmaiil.com

Answer (score 0):

> Add one id in a tag. and use this code
>
> ```
> <a href="#bookmark1" id="idaa">PAGE_NUMBER</a>
>
> $('#idaa').html();
> ```